# getRowSorter equivalent for JTable in Java 1.4

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, java1.4

Are there any equivalent functions for getting the sorting option for the headers in the JTable? Or are there any workarounds available?

Basically, I cannot execute this function because I am currently using Java 1.4, and upgrading the jdk is not an option.

```
if (table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(column).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
        return SortOrder.DESCENDING;
}
```

When compiling the code above it cannot find the method for getSortOrder().

Comment: [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) was introduced in Java 1.6, so there is no equivalent API available.

Comment: Are there any possible workarounds? Sorting is currently supported in our system. ((TableSorter) header.getTable().getModel()).sortByColumn(sortCol, ascending);

However in getting the sorting option for header seems not possible.

Answer (score 3):

[`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) was introduced in Java 1.6, so there is no equivalent API available for Java 1.4

Instead, if row sorting is important to you, you will need to implement a sorting mechanism of your own.

When I started with Java 1.3, we wrote a "proxy" model which would do a virtual sort (the proxy model would act as a wrapper around a `TableModel` and mapped the indices from the `TableModel` to the `JTable` so as to make it appear as if it was sorted)